# C# font able to be used after loading

Tags: c#, fonts

I figures out how to load a PS font from C# app,  it shows up and is useable in all the app on my system like word, notepad etc. except in my c# app (and of course this is where I needed it).

I need to assign that font to a textBox on my WinForm. Once I load the font I tried to assign the font to a text box like this: "GXSTRA03 is the font I loaded"

```
 printFont = new Font("GXSTRA03", 12);
 txtDisplyFont.Font = printFont;
```

But it always defaults to "Microsoft Sans Serif" Size=12.0

Below is the code I'm using to load the font:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
private static uint WM_FONTCHANGE = 0x1D;
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern int AddFontResource(string lpFilename);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern bool RemoveFontResource(string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private void LoadFont{
               int result = AddFontResource(@"C:\Temp\Font2\GXSTRA03.PFM|C:\Temp\Font2\GXSTRA03.PFB");
                long msg = SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Like I said above this works but not with my c# app so I thought I need to listen for the font change event like other app so I added the below code

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_FONTCHANGE:
                {
                    fontList();
                    break;
                }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);  // proceed with default processing
    }
```

I capture the system message that is sent to my app which tell me the font is list has changed.  When I receive the message I call a font List function to see if my app can see the font that was loaded.

```
private void fontList(){
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            InstalledFontCollection fontsCollection = new InstalledFontCollection();

            FontFamily[] fontFamilies = fontsCollection.Families;

            List<string> fonts = new List<string>();

            foreach (FontFamily font in fontFamilies)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(font.Name);

            }

      }
```

Within this list I thought I would see my font? Well I don't :-(  and I'm not sure what I missed or are doing wrong any help would be great at the moment I'm stuck..

Mike

Comment: Adobe Type 1 fonts are not usable from a Winforms app, it only supports TrueType fonts.  Maybe WPF but I doubt it, it has moved to OpenType.

Comment: ho boy never thought of that I'm going to have to come up with another approached. you should but this as an answer and I’ll accepted it.

Comment: Hi, just a quick question if I understand you correctly that if I have RichText component in my app and I want the user to pick a font that’s on the system and the one they wanted was a installed Postscript font they could not selected that font?

Comment: Wordpad uses RichTextBox.  Try it.

Comment: yes it works there like I said I can uses the font in any other applcation other than the one that loaded the font. whcih is mine but my app says the font don't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment, the font your are trying to use is an Adobe Type 1 font.  Which are not supported in Winform, it can only work with TrueType fonts.  The font mapper just won't enumerate it and you'll get a fallback font, Microsoft Sans Serif is the usual one.